# get ip of user executed program

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, drivers

In my kernel module driver, during the execution of program (e.g mkdir) I need to find out the IP of the currently logged in client that executed this program.

One solution is to climb up in the process tree, go to init process, then start going down in the process tree, look for sshd, cross between the user id and the sshd session, perform a netstat and get the Foreign Address.

Is the a better efficient way to get the ip of the user ?

Comment: You can look up remote IP in wtmp by user ID and current tty, but it is less reliable

Comment: why is it less reliable ?

Comment: What happens if they log in from ip X, schedule an `at` job, log out, and then that `at` job runs? What's the associated IP?

Comment: thanks for use case, in my module i dont audit these kinds of events so i dont mind for them, i only audit some specific directory operation events.

Comment: a process can detach itself from tty so you won't be able to match a wtmp record directly